# installing emacs on CentOS

Tags: linux, software-installation, emacs, vmware

I installed VMware and I have centOS installed in it and I'd like to install emacs on it but I don't find any source which has the tar file for that. I either find it for Linux or Solaris but when I tried installing the tar file given for Linux on VM it isn't installing. Can anyone give me the source where I can find the tar file for emacs that I can install on VM and also instructions on how to install it? I find using emacs easier than VIM. And what is the difference between Linux installed on disc and installed on a VM?

Comment: why can't you just `yum install emacs`?

Answer (score 7):

emacs is in the epel repos. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install emacs
```

Comment: sudo yum install epel-release ....... "already installed and latest version"
sudo yum install emacs ....... "no package emacs available"

Answer (score 2):

You can get source at: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/

Then use these commands.

```
tar -zxvf emacs-VERSION.tar.gz

cd emacs-VERSION

./configure        

make                

make install
```

Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Installing-Emacs.html

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second question,

When you install Linux on disc, you are going to use the kernel for the specific hardware that your machine has with the OS from that distro, if you use a VM instance, there should be a mid-layer between your machine (hardware) and the OS, this could be using extra modules from a kernel (like VMWare and Virtualbox) or creating a special kernel that has no proper OS like (Xen).

[image]

There is a performance difference in both operating system and operating system as VM, but it should be minimal unless you need to do some heavy processing.